# Unable to set light objects for Hue Lights

Tags: python, philips-hue

I am attempting to create groups using hue api using the following request:

```
Endpoint : /api/<userid>/groups
Method: POST
Params: {"name":"Test creation", "lights":["2","3"]}
```

I get the following response:

```
[{"success": {"id": "/groups/6"}}]
```

However when I call:

```
Endpoint : /api/<userid>/groups/6
Method: GET
```

I get this:

```
{"action": {"on": false,"effect": "none"},"lights": [],"name": "Test creation 2"}
```

It appears that the lights are not being set. I have not seen anywhere else to set the group members. I don't get an error just a blank array.

How do you properly set group members?

Comment: Your example works for me. What is the software version of your bridge? "swversion" in /config

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Hue environment has lights "2" and "3"?
Your /api//groups/6 (GET) response shows it has en empty array of lights.
Check your environment of lights. /api//lights (GET) are "2" and "3" present?

What result do you get when doing /api//groups/0? This should contain all lights.

Comment: Yes all lights are present when requesting the 0 group and all lights.

Comment: I have noticed that groups can only contain lights that are present at the moment of creation.
So try the following: validate if groups/0 has lights 2 and 3. Then do a POST to create a new group with ligths 2 and 3. Do a get on groups to see if the new group contains light 2 and 3.

Comment: Interesting observation. I will look into that. It may be that they need to be directly available to the bridge. Since each light acts as a repeater I wonder if there is a functionality difference between a light that is being repeated to, rather than directly connected to the bridge. I will experiment.